# Show image, if it's set in database

Tags: php, arrays, html, sqlite

I'm trying to show an image (or rather a link to an image) stored in a database and I'd like to get the image to show only if the link is set in the database. 
Currently, if the link is not set (value is null), it shows a broken link.

Is there a way to for example use an if-statement and echo a HTML-code?
Something like this:
(The value have been fecthed to array $current in this example:)

```
    <?php 
        if(isset($current['image']) {
           echo "<img src='<?php echo $current['image']; 
    ?>' class='left' style='max-height:20em; max-width:15em; margin-right:1em; margin-top:0;'})">
```

Comment: Yes that for sure is possible, dont forget the ending curly brace tho.

Comment: you code is ok,only put ending closing brace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, got it. 
-Solution:

```
<?php if(isset($current['image'])): ?><img src="<?php echo $current['image']; ?>" class="left" style="max-height:20em; max-width:15em; margin-right:1em; margin-top:0;})">
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `<?php` twice, you have problem with quotes, brackets, etc.

```
<?php

if (!empty($current['image'])) {
    echo "<img src='" . $current['image'] . "' class='left' style='max-height:20em; max-width:15em; margin-right:1em; margin-top:0;'>";
} else {
    // here you can write for example default no-image image or whatever yo want, if you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php 
  if(isset($current['image'])) {

    ?>
     <img src='<?php echo $current['image'];?>' class='left' style='max-height:20em; max-width:15em;        


      margin-right:1em; margin-top:0;'>
    <?php
     }
     ?>
```